# Dump and restore mongo database without mongodump command

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I need a way to produce a snapshot for a particular mongo database and be able to recreate that exact database on another server. I'm familiar with `mongodump` and `mongorestore` commands, **but** I need a single human-readable file (or better print everything to stdout) for the entire database, which `mongodump` doesn't do yet, which is known and expected and [here are the details why](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7860). I have two related questions.

First, does `mongodump` produce any other critical data besides collection names and indexes (when dumping a specific database) and if it does what is it? If I recall correctly, mongo might not like dumps made in different versions, which also might be a problem, is that true?

Second, if I manually extract collection names and index information, store it into a json of my own format, and then restore it on another server, will that be sufficient to create the identical database or would it be missing something?

Comment: Check mongoexport command. It exports data to CSV, TSV or JSON files.

Comment: You check mongoexport command and read what it does and how it differs from mongodump…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, does mongodump produce any other critical data besides collection names and indexes (when dumping a specific database) and if it does what is it?

`mongodump` produces a binary backup of your data, including the specific [BSON types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) that are used for fields. Additional metadata exported includes collection options (if you've changed any from the default) and index definitions. You can see this additional information in the `*.metadata.json` files created by `mongodump`.

> If I recall correctly, mongo might not like dumps made in different versions, which also might be a problem, is that true?

In general you should be able to replay older dumps with newer `mongorestore` versions. Some older versions of `mongodump` may not export all of the collection metadata you are expecting, so the general advice is to `mongodump` with at least the version of the `mongod` server you are running if not newer. One such example would be `mongodump` prior to 2.2, which did not create the `metadata.json` information so you would have to manually ensure indexes and collection option.

> Second, if I manually extract collection names and index information, store it into a json of my own format, and then restore it on another server, will that be sufficient to create the identical database or would it be missing something?

Assuming you recreate all the collection & index options (and correctly apply those when creating new collections) your database will be similar on the remote server but likely not identical.

The main difference will be the type integrity for fields (although this may not be of concern for your use case). BSON supports a richer set of data types than JavaScript. For example, JavaScript has a single Number type while BSON supports int32, int64, and double.

If your backup/restore process takes this into account using something like [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) to represent additional types, you can probably make the two databases more consistent.

Comment: That's perfect. I wasn't aware about metadata's role here, I'll look into this deeper. Big thanks!

Comment: One more quick thing, do I understand correctly that types relate to specific documents, not collections in general, and that what gets stored in the metadata?

Comment: No, the `metadata.json` is only to recreate the collection with the same options and indexes. Collection options are what you would pass to [`db.createCollection()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) or [`collMod`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/). The types of fields in documents are stored in each document.

Comment: @IanBytchek Also, I'm curious why you have a requirement for a "human-readable" format for the dump. I would use `mongodump` for backup rather than duplicating the effort of developing your own solution. You can use the [`bsondump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/bsondump/) tool included included with the MongoDB command-line tools to convert BSON into human-readable format if needed.

Comment: It's not a requirement it's a preference. I'm playing around putting together a project that does database migrations both for sql and mongo. Comparing the both, with sql databases you can dump everything into a single file which you can then compare against other dumps. With mongo not so easy. I've been storing the basic mongo schema (collections and indexes) in separate restorable json files for awhile, it works pretty well and it's easy to compare them. Now I'm trying to make this systematic and figuring out if this approach would cover other more complex cases.

Comment: So, really it would be ideal if mongo dump would allow sending all output directly into stdout. I know there's a request for that on jira but that's not a simple tweak nor high priority. I also agree that reinventing the wheel is a stupid idea, but with mongo it's so clean and simple in php that I don't see why not to have it as an initial implementation for schema only. I'll be looking further into mongo dump though as this is clearly the proper way of doing this. Would appreciate if you have any other advice on this.

Comment: @IanBytchek Are you interested in tracking data+schema changes or just the schema? I don't think `mongodump` sending output into stdout will help your use case, as the output would still be BSON (which is binary). I also think schema differences would be better tracked along with your application deployment rather than inferred from the data. If you want to have consistent schema (or required data, like lookup tables) you can always use an approach with delta migrations, but instead of having SQL deltas you would use JS deltas. The migration deltas can be checked into version control.

Comment: @IanBytchek I haven't tried any specific migration libraries for PHP, but there are a number available depending on your preferences and any framework(s) you are using, eg: [mongodb-migrations](https://github.com/antimattr/mongodb-migrations), [PHP Mongo Migrator](http://php-mongo-migrator.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [Yii2 Migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html#using-migrations).